# Drawing a graph with images and arrows with d3 issues

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a graph with d3 inserting images in node circles and drawing arrows on the target node. Nodes with images and edges are properly drawn, but the arrows are missing, although the marker is defined and used in links.
When I change the way nodes are attached to "g", arrows are drawn, but circle and images disappear. Can't figure out where the mistake stays.

D3 code is the following:

```
// define marker for the arrow
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["arrow"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

// add links
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#arrow)"; })
    .style("stroke", "#FF3300");


// add nodes
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("dblclick", dblclick)
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .style("fill", "#FFEBE6")
    .style("stroke", "#FF3300")
    .style("stroke-width", 3);

// add images - from base64
node.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
        if (d.imgB64) {
            return 'data:image/png;base64, ' + d.imgB64 ;
        }
    })
    .attr("x", -40)
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", 80)
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0.0);
    })
```

Comment: Can you include a bit of your data so that we may more easily reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code, arrows seems to be hidden/overlaid by the node circle and image. Changing the refX and refY attributes to 65 and 0 respectively addresses the issue.